# CrossApplication navigation with parameter in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

So I want to navigate from my application A to application B. Let's say my application B has the following url: https://enterprise/url/#ApplicationB-show?TableAppB=&/v4_Details/3113wqeqr

so the following coding you see here:

```
onNavigateButtonPressed: function() {
    var oCrossAppNavigator = sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation");
    if (sap.ushell && sap.ushell.Container && sap.ushell.Container.getService) {
        oCrossAppNavigator.toExternal({
            target: {
                semanticObject: "ApplicationB",
                action: "show"
            },
            params: {
                "TableName": "TableAppB",
            }
        });
    }
},
```

will only lead me to this url:
https://enterprise/url/#ApplicationB-show?TableAppB

how do I get that parameter /v4_Details/3113wqeqr behind it?

Comment: did you tried: 
params: {
                "TableName": "TableAppB",
                "anotherParamName": "/v4_Details/3113wqeqr"
            }

???

Comment: yes I did he will change that slash before that v4_Details into a percentage "%"

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems myself on CrossApp Navigation and subsequent routing matches. For instance, you want to navigate from App A to App B but with a certain hash pattern (as it appears you are doing) so that you navigate to a view besides the main one.

I think your best option might be to add as a parameter as Rafael mentioned, and then in your App B you should read the parameter before initializing its router (presumably in Component.js) and replace the `%` in the hash with a `/` (or any mutations you need). Hope it works!